# How to use pandas, agg over every n rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df and I would like to apply a function over subsets of 3 or 4 rows.

Specifically I want to compute of the gradient is increasing from row 0 to 2/3 row 2/3 to 5/7 etc. and save it in a new column.

I have a column I can use to group rows of 12 pid.
I figured I can do it this way

```
new_col = df[df.pid==1].T[subset of 3/4 cols].apply(np.gradient, axis=1)
```

And iterate over all pid.
But I know pandas has almost everything and I am aware of my lack of knowledge, so I am guessing there is a much smarter way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is possible add some sample data? What means `subset of 3/4 cols` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael apologies, here this is just the transpose so subset of 3 or 4 columns corresponds to every 3 or 4 rows. And the mask just makes the df have no more than 12 columns since there is 12 rows for every pid.

Comment: Not understand, why 3 rows, why 4? Maybe help  [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: I'm sorry @jezrael I'll study this and maybe ammend my question. I was actually trying to abstract to make it as easy to understand as possible.

The question below, if you are curious is actually a great solution to my problem.
Maybe it'll provide some insight into what I meant in the meantime (until I fix above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding this right, you could use the df.groupby().agg() syntax.

In the groupby method, your argument would be an identifier which splits up each 3/4 rows you need, and the the argument in the agg() method can take the form:

```
agg({"new_col_name": np.gradien})
```

This results in syntax that looks something like:

```
df.groupby(["grouping_id"]).agg({"new_col_name": np.gradient})
```

Where grouping_id column can be obtained by methods like cumcount(), rank(), depending on what you require.

Comment: Thank you! I think this does exactly what I need, I now only have to name my columns (which are integers atm). Thanks!!